# Fill all connected grid squares of the same type

Tags: algorithm, minecraft, traversal, grid-layout, graph-traversal

Foreword: I am aware there is another question like this, however mine has very specific restrictions. I have done my best to make this question applicable to many, as it is a generic grid issue, but if it still does not belong here, then I am sorry, and please be nice about it. I have found in the past stackoverflow to be a very picky and hostile environment to question askers, but I'm hoping that was just a bad couple people.

Goal(abstract): Check all connected grid squares in a 3D grid that are of the same type and touching on one face.

Goal(specific/implementation): Create a "fill bucket" tool in Minecraft with command blocks.
Knowledge of Minecraft not really necessary to answer, this is more of an algorithm question, and I will be staying away from Minecraft specifics.

Restrictions: I can do this in code with recursive functions, but in Minecraft there are some limitations I am wondering if are possible to get around. 1: no arrays(data structure) permitted. In Minecraft I can store an integer variable and do basic calculations with it (+,-,*,/,%(mod),=,==), but that's it. I cannot dynamically create variables or have the program create anything with a name that I did not set out ahead of time. I can do "IF" and "OR" statements, and everything that derives from them. I CANNOT have multiple program pointers - that is, I can't have things like recursive functions, which require a program to stop executing, execute itself from beginning to end, and then resume executing where it was - I have minimal control over the program flow. I can use loops and conditional exits (so FOR loops). I can have a marker on the grid in 3D space that can move regardless of the presence of blocks (I'm using an armour stand, for those who know), and I can test grid squares relative to that marker.

So say my grid is full of empty spaces only. There are separate clusters of filled squares in opposite corners, not touching each other. If I "use" my fillbucket tool on one block / filled grid square, I want it to use a single marker to check and identify all the connected grid squares - basically, I need to be sure that it traverses the entire shape, all the nooks and crannies, but not the squares that are not connected to that shape. So in the end, one of the two clusters, from me only selecting a single square of it, will be erased/replaced by another kind of block, without affecting the other blocks around it.

Again, apologies if this doesn't belong here. And only answer this if you WANT to tackle the challenge - it's not important or anything, I just want to do this. You don't have to answer it if you don't want to. Or if you can solve this problem for a 2D grid, that would be helpful as well, as I could possibly extend that to work for 3D.

Thank you, and if I get nobody degrading me for how I wrote this post or the fact that I did, then I will consider this a success :)

Comment: Can you have the fill expand over multiple time steps, instead of filling instantly?  The way to do that would be to place a "new" block, and then on every timestamp each new block replaces the appropriate neighbors with "new" blocks, and itself becomes a "done" block.

Comment: Yes indeed, that is perfectly allowable. I don't care how long it takes to execute, as long as it works. Also, my thing about no recursive functions may have been incorrect - it may be possible to create one, but it'd be very difficult I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

With help from this and other sources, I figured it out! It turns out that, since all recursive functions (or at least most of them) can be written as FOR loops, that I *can* make a recursive function in Minecraft. So I did, and the general idea of it is as follows:

For explaining the program, you may assuming the situation is a largely empty grid with a grouping of filled squares in one part of it, and the goal is to replace the kind of block that that grouping is made of with a different block. We'll say the grouping currently consists of red blocks, and we want to change them to blue blocks.

Initialization:

IDs - A objective (data structure) for holding each marker's ID (score)

numIDs - An integer variable for holding number of IDs/markers active

Create one marker at selected grid position with ID [1] (aka give it a score of 1 in the "IDs" objective). This grid position will be a filled square from which to start replacing blocks.

Increment numIDs

Main program:

FOR loop that goes from 1 to numIDs
{

at marker with ID [1], fill grid square with blue block

step 1. test block one to the +x for a red block

step 2. if found, create marker there with ID [numIDs]

step 3. increment numIDs

[//repeat steps 1 2 and 3 for the other five adjacent grid squares: +z, -x, -z, +y, and -y]

delete stand[1]

numIDs -= 1

subtract 1 from every marker's ID's, so that the next marker to evaluate, which was [2], now has ID [1].

} (end loop)

So that's what I came up with, and it works like a charm. Sorry if my explanation is hard to understand, I'm trying to explain in a way that might make sense to both coders and Minecraft players, and maybe achieving neither :P